# Drupal 6: How to keep multiple form elements in one line when creating custom form?

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-6

I have created a custom form & have four elements in there. 
I want to keep all those elements in one line. How to do it ?

I googled it and couldn't find anything relevant..if there is anything to be done by CSS then please suggest me where to put DIV in it.

I am pasting code below -

```
<?php

function taskform_form(&$node, $form_state)
{


  $form['date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date', 
    '#title' => t('Date'),        
  );

  $form['edproject'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#title' => t('Project'), 

    '#options' => array(
      1 => 'Konnected', 
      2 => 'eLearning', 
      3 => 'Others',
    ),
    '#description' => t('Choose a project'),
  );

  $form['task'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Task'), 
    '#size' => 30,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#maxlength' => 30,
    '#description' => t('Enter the task'),
  );

  $form['remarks'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea', 
    '#title' => t('Remarks'), 
    '#size' => 30,
    '#cols' => 6,
    '#description' => t('Enter remarks (If any).'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add Task'),
    '#submit' => array('taskform_form_submit'),
  );
  return $form;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the prefix and suffix property of the form elements and display it in the one line. Please see the code below if it will be useful for you.

```
function taskform_form(&$node, $form_state)
{
  $form['date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date', 
    '#title' => t('Date'),
    '#prefix' => '<table><tr><td>',
    '#suffix' => '</td>',   
  );

  $form['edproject'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#title' => t('Project'), 

    '#options' => array(
      1 => 'Konnected', 
      2 => 'eLearning', 
      3 => 'Others',
    ),
    '#description' => t('Choose a project'),
    '#prefix' => '<td>',
    '#suffix' => '</td>',
  );

  $form['task'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Task'), 
    '#size' => 30,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#maxlength' => 30,
    '#description' => t('Enter the task'),
    '#prefix' => '<td>',
    '#suffix' => '</td>',
  );

  $form['remarks'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea', 
    '#title' => t('Remarks'), 
    '#size' => 30,
    '#cols' => 6,
    '#description' => t('Enter remarks (If any).'),
    '#prefix' => '<td>',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr></table>',
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add Task'),
    '#submit' => array('taskform_form_submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Have you cleared your cache and see that the form is displaying in the table like structure.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the prefix and suffix to wrap the whole element in a div, and position the div from CSS. This way you can separate the structural info from the rendering.

Another option is to write custom theme functions that do the magic. However, I would opt for the prefix-suffix solution, as it is easier to maintain in the short run.

Check out [this quick tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/751826), the Theming Forms section describes your options.